# jQuery script ruined by variable assuming value 0 sometimes

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

My problem is that sometimes my script doesn't work. I know the problem but I can't solve it. Below, my script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* Cria UL e popula de LI de acordo com o HTML do controle da Vtex*/
$('.slider-nav').after('<ul class="slider-ul"></ul>');
/* clona elementos se tiver menos que 3 */
var tamArray = $('#slider .box-banner').length;
if (tamArray < 3) {
    for (ij=1; ij<=(3-tamArray); ij++){
        $('#slider .box-banner:last').clone().appendTo('#slider');
    }
}
$('#slider .box-banner').each(function(){
    href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    title = $(this).find('a').attr('title');
    src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('ul.slider-ul').append('<li><a href="'+href+'" title="'+title+'"><img src="'+src+'"/></a></li>');
});
$('.slider-ul').wrap('<div class="slider-ul-wrapper" />');
/* Calcula offset do left pra colocar um banner no meio */
var tamJanela = $(window).width();
var tamImagem = $('#slider .slider-ul:first img').width();
var leftOffset = tamImagem - (tamJanela-tamImagem)/2;
$('.slider-ul').css('left',-leftOffset);
/* Clique em #nav-dir */
$('#nav-dir').click(function(){
    $('.slider-ul li:last').clone().addClass('clone').insertBefore('.slider-ul li:first');
    var soma = -(leftOffset)-tamImagem;
    $('.slider-ul').css('left',soma);
    $('.slider-ul').animate({
        left: '+='+tamImagem+''
        //left: "'+="+tamImagem+"'"
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
        $('.slider-ul .clone').remove();
        $('.slider-ul li:last').insertBefore('.slider-ul li:first');
        $('.slider-ul').removeAttr('style');
        $('.slider-ul').css('left',-leftOffset);
    });
});
/* Clique em #nav-esq */
$('#nav-esq').click(function(){
    $('.slider-ul li:first').clone().addClass('clone').insertAfter('.slider-ul li:last');
    //var soma = -tamImagem;
    //$('.slider-ul').css('left',soma);
    $('.slider-ul').animate({
        left: '-='+tamImagem+''
        //left: "'+="+tamImagem+"'"
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
        $('.slider-ul .clone').remove();
        $('.slider-ul li:first').insertAfter('.slider-ul li:last');
        $('.slider-ul').removeAttr('style');
        $('.slider-ul').css('left',-leftOffset);
    });
});
});
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="slider-ul-wrapper">
    <ul class="slider-ul" style="left: 671.5px">
        <li>
            <a href="undefined" title>
                <img src="...." />
            </a>
        </li>
        .
        .
        .
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem happens when `tamImagem` evaluates the `img` element width to 0. It then passes the wrong value to `leftOffset` value and ruins the expressions. Sometimes, after several refreshes, it works. Sometimes it doesn't. What is the problem? Does it return 0 because the element isn't ready? But why wouldn't it be ready?

Also, there is some sort of Ajax request running on the background that I don't quite understand. Every image on the page receives a `complete` class when the requests are done.
Should I wait until the `img` element is `complete`? How do I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of an image, if not explicitly given in the html (as `width="xx"`), is normally not available until the document is fully loaded, i.e. `$(window).load()`.

At the time of `.ready()` all tags have been read and parsed, so any attributes pertaining to element dimensions can be read. If those attributes have not been set at this time, they will become available once the respective object has been loaded from its source.

If you want to be notified directly when a particular image has been loaded (as opposed to waiting for the `.load()`) you can attach an `.onload()` to it; no guarantees though, because image loading has already started by then and in some cases you would be too late to catch it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't get it, what's the difference between an element being loaded and being ready? Shouldn't `$(document).ready` already cover all the loading?

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato When the document is ready, all tags have been read and parsed, so attributes such as `width` can be read if they were part of the tag itself; at this time, the loading of external documents has started too (images mostly) and will all be available at `onload()`

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato no problem, I've updated my answer for others to see as well